# How to display values in a Kendo UI Grid custom popup template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC View with a simple Kendo UI Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Positions)    
    .Name("Test")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);                
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });        
    })       
    .Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Position").Window(w => w.Width(600)).Window(w => w.Title("Byrå")))

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))      
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Office"))        
        .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "Office")
     )
   )
 )
```

Under Shared/EditorTemplate I have added Postion.cshtml under Shared/EditorTemplates. The edit open as it shoulds and everything is fine if I use for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

However, I can't use LabelFor since that will display the name of the property and not the value. It also seems like the grid instantiate the popup together with the grid. The values in TextBoxFor is updated when I click on Edit, but if I use @Model.Name it does not. It will always be empty.

I also tried and hide some fields depending on the value of one of the fields, but since I can't use @Model it wont work.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

One of Kendo's answers to me was something like this. I haven't got it to work in my case yet, but it might help you. If you came up with a different solution to this issue could you share it?

In you custom editor.

text/javascript

```
function sendName() {
    var grid = $('.k-grid').data().kendoGrid;
    var tr = grid.tbody.find('.k-grid-edit-row');
    var model = grid.dataItem(tr);
    var result = {
        name: model.Name
    };
    return result;
}
```

They are inspecting the html and assigning first the grid, then the selected row of the grid then mapping the fields of the row to the columns of the Grid.